# How to show only a part of a plot of hazard ratio vs continuous variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, spline

Using the rms package and ggplot, I made a plot showing the hazard of a primary outcome vs a continuous variable (vdmr) using the code below (first image).

```
dd <- datadist(dat); options(datadist='dd')
spline <- cph(Surv(time, status) ~ rcs(vdmr, 4), data=dat)
ggplot(Predict(spline))
```

I would like to restrict the plot to only display the curve within a specific x-range (say, between 50 and 250; second image) but only after all values have been used to calculate the curve. This is similar to using xseq when applying it to geom_smooth, but I can't figure out how to integrate it in this context (outside of hacking it using photoshop). I'd appreciate any help.

[Current plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4dfB.png)

[My goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqZ90.png)

Comment: see `scale_x_continuous ()` in `ggplot2` this will show you how to limit your axis

Comment: `scale_x_continuous` changes the data, `coord_cartesian` wont

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. I know scale_x_continuous can change the range of the x-axis. What I'm after is keeping the x-axis scale, but crop what is displayed in the actual plot to a specific x value range - I'm not sure if my image attachments are coming through as I'm a new user, but you can get a sense of what I'm after looking at one vs the other. Thanks.